# fetch core data string by int in a parameter function

Tags: swift, string, integer, fetch, helper

In my swift code I attempted to fetch core data string using a int. I have 2 classes my base class and my helper class. In my base class that is where the func attempting to fetch the string. That func has a error message at    fetchImageTxt.text = String(data: imageData) stating Missing argument for parameter 'encoding' in call. Don't know how to resolve it.

BASE CLASS

```
     class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
      var fetchImageTxt = UITextField()

func getT(imageNo:Int) {
   // first check the array bounds
   let info = DataBaseHelper.shareInstance.fetchImage()
   if info.count > imageNo {
       // check if the data is available
       if let imageData = info[imageNo].img {
           fetchImageTxt.text = String(data: imageData)
           
           
       } else {
           // no data
           print("data is empty")
       }
   } else {
       // image number is greater than array bounds
       print("you are asking out of bounds")
   }
}
     }
```

HELPER CLASS

```
class DataBaseHelper {

static let shareInstance = DataBaseHelper()
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
func fetchImage() -> [Info] {
    
  
    var fetchingImage = [Info]()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Info")
    
    do {
        
        fetchingImage = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Info]
    } catch {
        print("Error while fetching the image")
    }
    
    return fetchingImage
}
}
```

[coreDataAttributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxs13.png)

Comment: “Don't know how to resolve it”, one suggestion is to add the missing parameter to the call…, [String(data:encoding:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/init(data:encoding:)). Please don’t post a question every time you get a simple compilation error

Comment: @JoakimDanielson that does not work I am still getting a error even after I have changed it to auto suggestion

Comment: What doesn't work, I have no idea what the auto suggestion is or what kind of error you get?